# $.getJSON call - losing click event on element

Tags: jquery, onclicklistener, getjson

Any one can tell me why the with the code below I get the alert "Hello world" working on link #1 and link #2 only?

The link #3 is generated after doing a ajax call and the click event seems to be simply not available. I can't figure it out why.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script src="media/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="media/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {

          $("#message").append('<a href="#" class="view_comments" id="2">Link #2</a><br />\n');

          $(".view_comments").click(function() 
            {
            alert('Yes it worked!');
          });

          UpdateDiv();

          function UpdateDiv() {
            var var_1 = "1";
            var var_2 = "2";
            $.getJSON('file.php', {var1: var_1, var2 : var_2},function(json_result){
              $("#message").append('<a href="#" class="view_comments" id="3">Link #3</a><br />\n');
              $("#message").show();
            });
          }

        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="message" name="message"><a href="#" class="view_comments" id="1">Link #1</a><br /></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Delegate](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) your `click` event:

```
$('body').on( 'click', ".view_comments", function()
```

Comment: should use closest element of DOM for performance, in OP case ``$("#message")``

Answer (score 0):

The click event is registered for already loaded items. Any element added dynamically don't seems having that event registered and hence the click event won't work. At least, I run into this issue before. But the following will fix it.

```
 $(".view_comments").on("click",function(){
 {
       //alert('Yes it worked!');
 });
```

Look the "on" JQuery API documentation

Comment: Please read the article: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Thank you, it worked! it was that simple... ;-))

Comment: Glad it helps! I run into this a while back and was scratching my head :)

Comment: Could you mark it as answered or vote -if it helped you, Terry. Thanks!